# Two Step authentication in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

[Authentication Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIFEv.png)

Firstly I am no pro, just started with IONIC framework.

I am trying to accomplish authentication as shown in the image above.

**What I am trying to do?**
Firstly, on loading my app, it checks if **user is logged in** or not. If user is logged in, then he/she will be redirected to Dashboard. 
If ***user is not logged in***, then system will check if the **user is waiting for verification code**.
 
If **user is waiting for verification code**, then INPUT verification Form will be displayed.
Else, user will be directed to INPUT username Form.

**What I have done so far?**
I have created 3 controllers for username input, verification code and dashboard. My service handles the back-end communication with my server and stores Authentication key and necessary user credentials on the local storage. 
I am using PHP SlimFramework for my REST API. 
**My Question**

1. How to check if user is logged in or is waiting for verification code, when the ionic app loads.

Comment: You can locally store a variable which contains the status of user and check the status on device ready situation and redirect according to that.

Answer (score 0):

**How check if user is Logged-in**

You can check if a user is logged-in by checking if a token key exists in the local storage like so:

```
    angular.module('starter')

    .service('AuthService', function($q, $http, USER_ROLES) {
        var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'yourTokenKey';
        var username = '';
        var isAuthenticated = false;
        var role = '';
        var authToken;

    function loadUserCredentials() {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
        if (token) {
          useCredentials(token);
        }
    }

    function storeUserCredentials(token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY, token);
        useCredentials(token);
    }

    function useCredentials(token) {
        username = token.split('.')[0];
        isAuthenticated = true;
        authToken = token;

        if (username == 'admin') {
          role = USER_ROLES.admin
        }
        if (username == 'user') {
          role = USER_ROLES.public
        }

        // Set the token as header for your requests!
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = token;
    }

    function destroyUserCredentials() {
        authToken = undefined;
        username = '';
        isAuthenticated = false;
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = undefined;
        window.localStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    }

    var login = function(name, pw) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      if ((name == 'admin' && pw == '1') || (name == 'user' && pw == '1')) {
        // Make a request and receive your auth token from your server
        storeUserCredentials(name + '.yourServerToken');
        resolve('Login success.');
      } else {
        reject('Login Failed.');
      }
    });
    };

    var logout = function() {
        destroyUserCredentials();
    };

    var isAuthorized = function(authorizedRoles) {
        if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
          authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
        }
        return (isAuthenticated && authorizedRoles.indexOf(role) !== -1);
    };

        loadUserCredentials();

        return {
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        isAuthorized: isAuthorized,
        isAuthenticated: function() {return isAuthenticated;},
        username: function() {return username;},
        role: function() {return role;}
    };
```

This is a typical example of a User Authentication Service. Here on loading the app, you check if the authorized token exists, if it doesn't it means the user is logged out.

You can also apply similar technique for checking if the user is waiting for verification code.

**Verification code technique**

1. There could be a field in your database that is set to `false` once the verification code has been sent out for a particular user.
2. Once the user gets the code and inputs it into form, it checks the code against the database, if it's valid, it then marks the `verified` field as `true`.

You might want to check out this very good [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/) for how to handle authentication in your Ionic app.

If you are using Ionic 2, you can check out this comprehensive [tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/).  Auth0 also handles [2-factor Authentication](https://auth0.com/learn/two-factor-authentication/)  really well.

I hope this helps! Cheers!